# recargar automaticamente una pagina al dar click en volver atras en el explorador

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, formularios

Hola buenos días quiero saber si hay la manera de hacer que una pagina se recargue automáticamente ya que tengo problemas al momento de dar el botón volver en el explorador no se genera códigos nuevos, y debo actualizar la pagina para que esoo suceda

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos lo que has realizado?

Comment: muestro con un echo los siguiente consulta $sql = "select
        concat('CLIEN',
        (CASE WHEN max(s.cont_codigo) IS NOT NULL THEN
      LPAD(SUBSTR(max(s.cont_codigo),10)+1,10,0)
        ELSE '0000000001'
        END)) as CODIGO
        from spm_contacto s";
        $robot = $this->db->fetchOne($sql); echo  $robot["CODIGO"]

Comment: Si una página se carga mediante una petición HTTP POST, cuando vuelve hacia atras el navegador debe mostrar un aviso pidiendo al usuario si quiere recargar la página. Otra opción es cargar los códigos no con la página sino mediante Ajax.

Comment: Hola @Jhosep. ¿Podrías aclarar un poco qué estás tratando de hacer y qué intentaste hasta ahora? ¿La idea es recargarla apenas se vuelve a una página con el botón *back*? ¿O intentás recargarla cada X segundos? ¿Para recargarla, se recarga completamente desde el servidor, o es una parte específica que se tiene que actualizar por AJAX? Además, ¿por qué todas esas etiquetas? ¿En qué lenguaje estás trabajando?

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
<script type="text/javascript">
    onload = function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("refreshed");
        if (e.value == "no")
            e.value = "yes";
        else {
            e.value = "no";
            location.reload();
        }
    }</script> si verifique varias paginas esto era lo que queria hacer

Comment: por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega todo lo que has puesto en los comentarios! salutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Añade esta cabecera a tu PHP para asegurarte que no devuelve una página cacheada:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Muchisimas gracias por su ayuda realmente esto queria hacer y me funciono talves si hay otra forma de interpretarla valdria q me ayuden pero esto queria hacer

```
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      onload = function () {
         var e = document.getElementById("refreshed");
         if (e.value == "no")
             e.value = "yes";
         else {
             e.value = "no";
             location.reload();
         }
     }</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal si usas PHP es que cuando se proceso el formulario en php (recoger variables y meterlas en una base de datos por ejemplo) hacer una dirección con un header.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php //ejemplo

$datos = $_REQUEST['datos'];
$sql = "INSERT tabla SET datos = '" . $datos . "'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
header("Location:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //la pagina anterior o poner la pagina que tu quieras
die();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes creo que he entendido mal la pregunta. Si quieres volver a la página anterior como actúa el botón de retroceso del navegador entonces tendrías que usar el objeto history. Puedes usar la siguiente función:

```
window.history.back()
```

Puedes encontrar la documentación (en español) sobre este elemento [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Manipulando_el_historial_del_navegador).

Comment: ¿Y cómo se haría que se ejecutara al ir atrás en la historia? Es la parte "divertida" del problema.

Comment: @SJuan76 Podrías hacer un `location = window.location.href` apuntando a la url en la que se encuentra la página anterior. Igual estoy entendiendo mal la pregunta. Después tendrías que usar `location.reload(true);`

Comment: El unico problema es que el boton no es mio es el boton de el explorador a lo que se da click y hay vno le puedo poner

Comment: @JHOSEPLUISLOORANDRADE Ahora creo que he entendido el problema. ¿Lo que quieres es que te detecte la página anterior desde la página actual no?

Comment: @JHOSEPLUISLOORANDRADE He editado la respuesta. Espero que esta vez sea lo que necesitas.

Comment: @SJuan76 He vuelto a releer la pregunta y creo que ahora la he entendido bien. Ya he editado la respuesta.

Comment: el reload esta bien pero debe hacerese solo una ves  se me hace varias veces con un bucle infinito con lo siguiente  <script type="text/javascript">
            
            function refresh()
            {
                    location.reload(true);
            }
    </script>
    <body onload="refresh">

Comment: @JHOSEPLUISLOORANDRADE ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir entonces? No sé si es que estoy entendiendo muy mal tu pregunta pero me parece que sí.